# loosing datacontexts when switching contentcontrol content

Tags: wpf, datacontext, contentcontrol

i am making a navigation shell system with a ContentControl and a bunch of buttons .

each button is responsible to instansiate a different UserControl type and put it in the ContentControl .
i have also an ObservableCollection of all the opened usercontrols

```
public ObservableCollection<UserControl> OpenedWindowsList = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>();
```

so for button1 for example i have this

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var w = OpenedWindowsList.Where(a => a is MyUserControl1).FirstOrDefault();
    if (w == null)
    {
        ADHERANT adh = new ADHERANT(); // my EF object that serve as datacontext

        MyUserControl1 UC = new MyUserControl1();
        UC.DataContext = adh;


        OpenedWindowsList.Add(UC);

        MainContentControl.Content = UC;

    }
    else
    {
        MainContentControl.Content = w;
    }
}
```

and basically this is the same for other navigation buttons in my main window .

**so i click on Button1 :**

- the usercontrol is created and it's associated datacontext

**i click on another button (button2)**

- again another usercontrol is created and it's associated datacontext

but when i come back to button1 , i have the same previously created  usercontrol but it's **datacontext is null** !!

any idea on whats going on is welcome
thanks

Comment: Please consider using MVVM pattern and some framework that handles navigation, dependency injection, binding automatically. You can see some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069783/which-mvvm-framework-is-the-best-framework-for-wpf-apps

Comment: Please provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It is not reproducible based on the information you have given.